# wordpress lightbox gallery on button click

Tags: wordpress, gallery, lightbox

In "project" page on my site i have some photos and a button "Check how it looked before".
[image]

Is there a way to make wordpress gallery pop-up in a lightbox on button-click AND make it easy to access through admin-panel (without any coding, just add photos to gallery and attach to button)?
I am using foobox as a lightbox plugin and a standard gutenberg wordpress gallery.

Comment: As far as I know with Foobox, there's no way to use a button to trigger a gallery without coding. Would you be able to add custom code or do you have to only use plugins?

Comment: hey, thanks for answer,
Sure, I can do some custom code but I need to make it easy to access for a person that can't. I can make a static version of on-click lightbox gallery(the site is on bootstrap, so it would not be too hard), but I have no idea how to connect it with wordpress admin panel.